Saving limited records per TestCase name in Mongodb
I am working on a framework to save test data for QA test cases in mongodb. I want to save only 20 test data per api request. e.g. if api call is for member summary then I want to limit saving only 20 test datas and after 20 records no test data should be saved even if the api gets called.
is there any query for it?

You can use Change Streams to create such logic. But, change streams require that your deployment is a replica-set cluster (not a standalone deployment).
